# How to save the answers of a specific user to his profile in the questionnaire app (SwiftUI)?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am creating an app for parents or guardians of autistic children. In the app, you can create **profiles for several kids** and then click on the "Start Questionnaire" button in the personal card of each child. When the questionnaire page opens, there the parent answers **several questions in several categories**, where the questions from each category have **a different weight** (1, 2, 3, 4). At the end of the questionnaire, these answers are recorded in the profile of a particular kid in order to display a graph of his progress based on the answers on his personal page.

My question is that I can't figure out how to save answers to a specific kid's profile. To store profiles of children, I use **CoreData**, where there are four attributes: name, birthdate, dateCreated and **answers**. I assigned the **Binary Data** type to the latter. I created a @State variable in the QuestionnairePageView file and specified its type as **[[String:Int]]** to store a question category as a String (1, 2, 3 or 4) and an answer as an Int (yes = 1 or no = 0). Also in that file I created a **saveAnswers function** that assigns questionnaire answers to that @State variable when the user taps **End Questionnaire button**.
However, it didn't work. Please help me to understand the issue.

[image]

My data manager:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    static let shared: CoreDataManager = CoreDataManager()
    
    private init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PersonModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to initialize Core Data \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My QuestinarrieApp file:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct QuestinarrieApp: App {
    let controller = CoreDataManager.shared.container

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, controller.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

My ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingAddPersonPage: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Person.ownFetchRequest)
    var persons: FetchedResults<Person>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(persons) { person in
                        let age = "\(calculateAge(fromDate: person.birthdate ?? Date()))"
                        
                        NavigationLink {
                            PersonalPageView(person: person, name: person.name ?? "Noname", age: age)
                        } label: {
                            HStack {
                                Text(person.name ?? "Noname").font(.title2.bold())
                                Spacer()
                                Text(age + " years old").font(.body.bold())
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                    .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                            )
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Persons")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        isShowingAddPersonPage = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    } //: BUTTON
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingAddPersonPage) {
                        AddPersonView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let container = CoreDataManager.shared.container
        
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

My AddPersonView file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddPersonView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var birthdate: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                // MARK: - NAME
                HStack(spacing: 12) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.text.rectangle")
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                } //: HSTACK
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(height: 60)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                )
                
                // MARK: - BIRTH DATE
                HStack(spacing: 12) {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    
                    DatePicker(
                        "Birth date",
                        selection: $birthdate,
                        in: ...Date(),
                        displayedComponents: .date
                    )
                    .accentColor(.black)
                    
                } //: HSTACK
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(height: 60)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                )
                
                Spacer()
                
                // MARK: - SAVE BUTTON
                Button {
                    if name != "" {
                        savePerson()
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                        .font(.body.bold())
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 60)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                        )
                } //: BUTTON
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Person")
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    private func savePerson() {
        let newPerson = Person(context: viewContext)
        
        do {
            newPerson.name = name
            newPerson.birthdate = birthdate
            newPerson.dateCreated = Date()
            
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

struct AddPersonView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let container = CoreDataManager.shared.container
        
        AddPersonView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

My PersonalPageView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PersonalPageView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    var person: Person
    var name: String
    var age: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                Text(name).font(.largeTitle.bold())
                Spacer()
                Text(age + " years old").font(.title2.bold()).foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .frame(height: 300)
            
            VStack {
                ForEach(person.answers) { answer in // <- This ForEach doesn't work for now
                    Text("\(answer)")
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            NavigationLink {
                QuestinarriePageView(person: person, name: "Jack")
            } label: {
                Text("Start Questinarrie")
                    .font(.title2.bold())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                    )
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct PersonalPageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PersonalPageView(person: Person(), name: "Igor", age: "28")
    }
}
```

And finally QuestinarriePageView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct QuestinarriePageView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var answers: [[String:Int]] = [[:]]
    
    var person: Person
    var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Quit").font(.title2)
                }
                .tint(.black)
            }
            
            VStack {
                Text("Does \(name) like to play with other kids?")
                HStack(spacing: 100) {
                    Button {
                        answers += [["1":1]]
                    } label: {
                        Text("Yes")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(.secondary)
                            )
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        answers += [["1":0]]
                    } label: {
                        Text("No")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(.secondary)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Text("Does \(name) like to speak?")
                HStack(spacing: 100) {
                    Button {
                        answers += [["2":1]]
                    } label: {
                        Text("Yes")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(.secondary)
                            )
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        answers += [["2":0]]
                    } label: {
                        Text("No")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(.secondary)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Text("Does \(name) like to play dance?")
                HStack(spacing: 100) {
                    Button {
                        answers += [["3":1]]
                    } label: {
                        Text("Yes")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(.secondary)
                            )
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        answers += [["3":0]]
                    } label: {
                        Text("No")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(.secondary)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                saveAnswers()
            } label: {
                Text("End Questionnaire")
                    .font(.body.bold())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                    )
            }
        }
        .toolbar(.hidden)
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func saveAnswers() {
        let thisPerson = person
        do {
            thisPerson.answers = answers as? Data

            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

struct QuestinarriePageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        QuestinarriePageView(person: Person(), name: "Igor")
    }
}
```

Also I have a file with some helpers:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

func calculateAge(fromDate: Date) -> Int {
    let now = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: fromDate, to: now)
    let age = ageComponents.year!
    
    return age
}

extension Person {
    static var ownFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: false)]
        
        return request
    }
}
```

I've been struggling with this problem for a month now. I hope this is solvable

[image]

Comment: May need a better reproducible code.

Comment: @tail
I changed the code and screenshots a bit so that the code became a better reproducible

Comment: May be I am wrong but answer is a array of dictionaries. It should just just a dictionary. You should not add an answer but set the category answer : answer[x]=1  .also use an array of question so you can add one more easily and use ForEach to not repeat the same code each time. In your case you continuously add new answer instead of replacing the previous one. If you want an history you should also save the answer date.